# Fastest collection for concurrent read and write other than Java Collections

Tags: java, collections

I have a requirement to store Strings into a collections. The Collection will hold billions of strings.

The collection must support fast look up, add , delete in a concurrent manner.

Is there any know fast, low latency collections available besides Java collections...

I searched but didn't come across anything interesting...

Comment: What platform are you planning to use? "billions" of strings on a computer with how much memory (32GB .. would allow you to store less than 1 billion 16 character strings (UTF-8).

Comment: Sorry forgot to wrote the platform. I am looking for Java. Well i am taking right now for the worst case scenerio

Comment: What do you mean by "besides Java collections"? I'd consider any collection written in Java as a "Java collection". Do you mean collections in Java not in the standard API (i.e. in some external library)? Note that that would be off topic, see the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Dukeling : Yes i mean outside the jDK collections area...

Comment: What are the maximum sizes of the strings you will need to hold?

Comment: well its will be user input...so is unpredictable...but if there is no nonsense input than yes than between 25-30 characters than but was searching and came across ArrayDeque ...not sure if it will be the best fit..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hold billions of strings of any reasonable length on a reasonable cost server you will need to use the strategy I have outlined below. First consider the implications of "billions" of Strings:

- Do a storage calculation (e.g. for up to 10 billion strings, with 64 characters per string average): 1.28 trillion bytes = 10 billion x 64 x 2 (UTF-8 will need at least 2 bytes per character)

That means one cannot use storage on a computer to hold all the strings.

The required storage capacity drives one to use external storage ... most flexible would be to use a database, fronted by a cache in mamory. Since Collection is simply an interface, you can implement this huge storage for strings using a collection (that would internally look up strings and would handle "overflow" to database.

Further implications: there are some required methods that would have to return a null or error, since they would not have the storage to produce results, for example

- toArray, toArray

So .. to answer your question, you would need to implement your own Collection for "huge capacity", and perhpas your own caching (or use a product like ehcache .. just for example, not a recommendation)